# Declare verbatim character in Replace expression

Tags: c#

I have a `string.Replace` statement to change characters in a string from `'\'` to `';'`.
Problem is that I need to mark the char of `'\'` as verbatim, which could be done in a string as `@"stringtext\"` but i cant seem to find a expression to do this with a character.
Is there a way to declare a character as "verbatim" to be able to use `'\'` in a character statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx) it seems it is not possible to write a verbatim `char` literal. You either have to escape the backslash:

```
somestring.Replace('\\', ';')
```

Or specify the character using its Unicode codepoint:

```
somestring.Replace('\u005C', ';')
```

Comment: I am aware of that possibility, but I was curious if there is a char version of the verbatim expression. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can just escape the character like this:

```
char myChar = '\\';
```

Answer (score 0):

verbatim a char does not make sense.The whole idea behind verbatim is you do not have to repeatedly escape characters in your string. As in case of char, you can just escape single character.